# How to generate random number series from 1 to 200 with a particular condition, using matlab?

Tags: matlab

Using Matlab, how to generate from a set of 200 numbers {1,2,3, ..., n, n +1, ..., 200}, 10000 random series of 20 numbers with the following condition: 
for two numbers x and y of each serie, abs(x-y)/50 different from 0,1,2 and 3.

for example:
if 57 is part of one serie, I do not want to have in this serie: 7 or another 57 or 107 or 157

Comment: *for two numbers x and y of each serie, |x-y|/50 different from 0,1,2 and 3.*  I'm sorry, I don't understand this statement.  Can you edit your post with an example?

Comment: OK, so basically when you draw a number randomly... let's say, 3.  You want to ensure that 53, 103 and 153 don't show up?  After, let's say we draw 5.  You don't want 55, 105 or 155 to show up?

Comment: yes! this is what I want, but even 3 and 5 should not appear 2 times or more .

Comment: Found some errors in my code.  It is now fixed.  Take a look.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two steps:

- First generate 20 unique numbers between 1 and 50
- Second decide which region they fall in (0-50,51-100,101-150,151-200)

The first step can be done with `randperm` and the second with `randi`, so to generate one row;

```
row = randperm(50,20)+(randi(4,1,20)-1)*50
```

sadly `randperm` cant be used directly to generate the 10000 rows required

---

A simple loop can be used to genreate the 10000 series;

```
n=10000;
data=zeros(20,n);
for ii=1:n
data(:,ii) = randperm(50,20)+(randi(4,1,20)-1)*50;
end
```

---

### Custom Probabilities

With a **column** vector of probabilities `prob=[p1;p2;p2;p4]` for the ranges 0-50,51-100,101-150 and 151-200 respectively (which will be used for the second decision above)
the `(randi(4,1,20)-1)` term can be replaced with `sum(bsxfun(@ge,rand(1,20),p))` where p is defined below...

which can be implemented as follows

```
p = cumsum(prob) % last entry of p should =1
row = randperm(50,20)+sum(bsxfun(@ge,rand(1,20),p))*50
```

which could also simply be put within the loop to generate 10000 series

Comment: `randperm` is being called right.  I'm not sure why you're getting that error.

Comment: possibly shadowed, try `which randperm` should return built-in with a file path, also this code is almost certainly faster, took  <1 sec on my laptops 1.8GHz i3 (directly from command window). edit coming for custom probabilities as asked in other answer

Comment: @bzak edit added, also interestingly the `bsxfun` approach allowing custom probabilites for decision 2 decreased execution time

Comment: @bzak intresting... it is possible your Matlab version predates the 2 input version of randperm.  Try replacing calls to `randperm` with calls to `randp` after defining the anonymous function randp as follows: `randp=@(n,k)builtin('_paren',randperm(n),1:k)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `randsample` and specify **weighted** probabilities when you want to draw a random sample from a population.  What you can do is the following (for one iteration):

1. Start with a sequence from 1 to 200
2. Start a loop and start with a PDF that makes drawing each number equiprobable
3. For each iteration in the loop...

   - Draw a number
   - Set the probabilities of those numbers that satisfy your condition to be zero.
   - Redistribute the probabilities so that you make the rest of them equiprobable
4. Repeat 3 until we hit 20 times

As such, here's the code for 10000 iterations (outer most `for` loop).  The inner most `for` loop does the algorithm above.

```
randomNumbers = zeros(10000, 20);

for i = 1 : 10000
    seq = 1 : 200; %// Step #1
    probs = (1/200)*ones(1,200); %// Step #2

    for j = 1 : 20
        %// Generate number according to condition
        %// Step #3a
        num = randsample(200, 1, true, probs);
        %// Store number
        randomNumbers(i,j) = num;

        %// Generate numbers that should not
        %// appear in the next iteration / sampling
        seq2 = 1 : 200;
        seq3 = abs(seq2 - num) / 50;
        flags = seq3 == 0 | seq3 == 1 | seq3 == 2 | seq3 == 3;
        numbersToDiscard = seq2(flags);

        %//Figure out how many numbers are left that
        %//we can generate
        seq(numbersToDiscard) = 0;
        totalLeft = sum(seq ~= 0);

        %// Calculate new probabilities for generation            
        probs = (1/totalLeft)*ones(1,200); %//Step #3b and #3c
        probs(seq == 0) = 0;
     end
end
```

`randomNumbers` will be your randomly generated sequence.  Each row consists of a 20 sample sequence based on the rules above, and you have 10000 sequences in total.

**NB:** I just ran this code on my computer.  It is an Intel i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40 GHz with 16 GB of RAM running MATLAB R2014a on Windows 7 Ultimate.  This took about 6.27 seconds.  This is probably because I am generating a single number at each iteration and recomputing the probability of drawing on the fly.  This will take some time, so I hope you're patient!

Comment: @bzak: I found some errors in my code.  I fixed it a few minutes ago.  Please use the above.  It is updated.

Comment: thank you very much for this answer. It has given me more ideas! If I want to select the numbers in the different sequences  1-50,51-100,101,150 and 151-200  with different probabilities how to modify this program to get the result? for example prob(select numbre between 1 and 50)=p1, prob(select numbre between 51 and 100)=p2, prob(select numbre between 101 and 150)=p3 and prob(select numbre between 151 and 200)=p4

Comment: @bzak: You can modify this by changing Step #2 to: `probs(1:50) = p1; probs(51:100) = p2; probs(101:150) = p3; probs(151:200) = p4;`  You would eliminate Step #3b and #3c, assuming that the rule has now changed.

Comment: after several run, I noticed sometimes that the program gives repeated values!!

Comment: With the above modification, yes there will be repeated values.  **However**, with the first version, every time you start a new iteration, the **probabilities** reset itself... so obviously.  If you enforce the same rule over all of the iterations, you will eventually run out of numbers to generate.  That's why they need to reset at each iteration.